# How do I get from search_theme_directories() to the $stylesheet (name) for switch_theme()

Tags: theme-development, switch-theme

I have a theme. It depends on a plugin. If you try to activate the theme and the plugin isn't installed, then I want to [`switch_theme()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme) to some other (random**) theme in the  [`search_theme_directories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/search_theme_directories) list.

I can get the `$template` value from the key of the array returned by [`search_theme_directories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/search_theme_directories). But I can't seem to sort out how to get the `$stylesheet`.

Also, given this approach, what's the best way to check if a theme is child or a parent? Without getting into details I would prefer to pick parent theme as a default.

Perhaps there's a better way to do this? I would presume WP has something similar built in but I can seem to pin point that either. In short, I'm listenin' if you got ideas :)

**Important**

I was not able to tag this with: `search_theme_directories()`. That tag doesn't exist and I don't have the rep to add it. Could someone with some juice add it to the list of valid tags? Thanks.

Note: I'm first going to check for twentytwelve and twentyeleven and then if necessary pick one if they aren't around.

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't seem to sort out how to get the $stylesheet.

Easy.

```
$themes = search_theme_directories();

// a random theme
$themename = array_rand($themes,1); 

// that random theme's stylesheet
$stylesheet = content_url('/themes/'.$themes[$themename]['theme_file']);

// The absolute path to that theme's stylesheet
$stylepath = WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/themes/'.$themes[$themename]['theme_file'];
```

Getting a random theme that is not a child is more involved. I think this is it, though. It works in testing but don't consider it rigorously tested.

```
$themes = search_theme_directories();
$rand_theme = false;
while (!$rand_theme) {
  if (empty($themes)) {
    break;
  }
  $themename = array_rand($themes,1);
  $theme_obj = wp_get_theme($themename); 
  // Parent themes don't have a 'Template'
  $template = $theme_obj->get('Template');
  if (empty($template)) {
    $rand_theme = $themename;
    break;
  } else {
    unset($themes[$themename]);
  }
}
switch_theme($rand_theme);
```

[`wp_get_theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme) returns a Theme Object. I set `$rand_theme` to the theme name since that is what `switch_theme` expects.

As is, that will switch themes on every page load. Drop that into the plugin directory and you have yourself a pretty annoying plugin :)

Comment: Thx @s_ha_dum but I don't think the first bit is going to work. For example, this is what works to switch to twentytwelve: switch_theme('twentytwelve','twentytwelve'); Notice how "stylesheet" ain't really so. I tried a number of different things, yours included and this is the only thing that work. As for get_the_theme(). If that gives me an object with theme details then that'll do. Cheers! Perhaps you can take another shot at the first bit?

Comment: What 'first bit' are you talking about? I dropped that code into a plugin file and it randomly switches themes on every page load as long I as keep reloading. I just re-pasted that second block from that plugin file just in case I had something wrong.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Specifically, this: $stylesheet = content_url('/themes/'.$themes[$themename]['theme_file']); I tried that and WP didn't like it. switch_theme() doesn't want/need the folder structure. it wants a name. e.g.  switch_theme('twentytwelve','twentytwelve'); http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme. This is what had be confused and in search of a viable solution. Thanks again for your help.